# What does this sentence mean

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence mean?

> Explore how Lee's writing here vividly conveys to you the drama in the courtroom.

Comment: It means you should read all of _To Kill a Mockingbird_ before you go back to the courtroom scene and re-read it carefully. Then think about the question.

Comment: Or question the sentence.

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited to SE.Writers. http://writers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Think about the story of what happens in the courtroom, the emotions that you think the characters are feelings, the profound effects that the events of the courtroom have on those characters' lives-- that's the drama. Then look at the writing and find the words and phrases and paragraphs that most clearly showed you these emotions the characters were feeling and the importance of the events for them. Find those words Lee wrote, the ones that told you the story really well. Then use those parts as examples of how her writing "conveys to you the drama in the courtroom." Explain why you think those parts of the writing were so effective, too.